# java script plugin for playing media like youtube

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, jsp

In my spring based project I need to play audio/video in any format and will be similar to you tube ,so I am trying to find out js plugin which may be the best and free of cost.

It will be very helpful if I get some suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Why its tagged as `java`,`spring`??

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[videogular](http://www.videogular.com/)**

```
angular.module('myApp',
        [
            "ngSanitize",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.buffering",
            "luegg.directives"
        ]
    )
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/u20ux2?p=info)**